Why do Baryonic acoustic oscillations imply peaks in the probability distribution of the position of galaxies?
I have been trying to understand baryonic acoustic oscillations (BAO) and there are some parts of the process I don't understand.

We start with a  hot plasma of baryons and photons. There's also dark matter but it doesn't see the photons.

There are regions with slight overdensities that start to clump due to gravity. As I understand it, the locations of these mass overdensities are not dictated by any physics related to the BAO's. If anything, there distancing has to do with the length of primordial quantum fluctuations or something like that.

Because gravity compresses the plasma, we get more radiation pressure and the overdense region becomes essentially a source of sound waves. Goes in, goes out, goes in, goes out, emitting pressure waves through the plasma.

At some point, recombination happens, photons become free and the pattern of oscillations becomes frozen in space.


Now, I don't understand how this translates to peaks in the probability of correlations between the galaxy populations across the sky. The original positions of the overdensities was random, or at least unrelated to the oscillations, so they are not going to be correlated. Furthermore, each overdensity was frozen at a different time of the oscillation, so some will be overdensities, some underdensities. People usually show a picture like this:

But that would mean that every oscillation started at the same time, which I don't think is what's happening.
Also, in these depictions people show only one ring, coming closer and further. But if the overdensities are sources of pressure waves, shouldn't we get consecutive rings as the pressure fronts propagate from the overdensity? Is the distance between different fronts what we measure as a correlation?
In short my  question is: What distance is the peak in the probability distribution of positions of galaxies? Is it the distance between an overdensity and the first peak of its pressure wave? is it the distance between  different overdensities? Is it the distance between each peak of the pressure waves produced by the overdensities?

Every oscillation did start at the same time. That time is the beginning of the Universe. Initial variations in the density of the Universe might have been sourced dynamically by something like inflation (this is where the "primordial quantum fluctuations" verbiage comes in), but that is not important; what matters is that by the time of the Universe's first second, they were all there.
Regions of excess density are not continuous sources of sound waves. The initial density variations propagate outward at the speed of sound, and that's it.
The distance scale that is imprinted in the galaxy correlation function is the sound horizon, the (comoving) distance that sound waves were able to travel between the beginning of the Universe and the time of recombination.

Thanks so much! That answers most of my questions. So the overdensities did start contracting all at the same time, and they only emited one shell outwards, they were not constants sources of waves. But then why do people usually refer to "overdensities that had time to contract once" or "contract and expand" refering to how many cycles of contraction and expansion the oscillation did

The "oscillations" in the name refer to oscillations in frequency ($k$) space, such as in the angular power spectrum of the cosmic microwave background or in the matter power spectrum. The single length scale in real space is associated with an oscillatory pattern in frequency space. It's hard to say more generally what justifies particular descriptions, but calculations are usually done in frequency space, which can give a pretty different intuition from real space.

I think it makes more sense now. Let me ask one last question to see if I get it. One common plot I see is the histogram of number of galaxies as a function of distance between them. This gives a decaying function with distance, with one bump at the sound horizon, which is due to the BAO's. As I understand it, there was one single wave leaving every overdensity at the same time, so the peak is at the sound horizon. Now, the reason why the power spectrum of the CMB has many bumps... is it because it plots power as a function of l, which is technically frequency space?

That's exactly right.

Continuing: In a plot in terms of distance you would get a single distance L, which is the radius of the sound horizon. But when you transform that into spherical harmonics and go to frequency space, you get all multiples of $k_n=\pi n /L $ which are all the peaks in the power spectrum of the cmb, is that right? I know we are not doing a Fourier transform but a transform in terms of spherical harmonics, but roughly that would be the frequency i guess...

Yeah, the spherical geometry should smear the peaks a bit, but that's the essence.

That makes sense! I don't know if you have time to watch 5 minutes of a video, but I guess my follow up question is: Is the explanation here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4CKtEQJGMY complete nonsense then? He talks about the different overdensities having time to expand and contract many number of times and the ones that got caught at max or minimum density at the time of recombination are responsible for the peaks on the CMB's power spectrum... That is a complete different explanation than simply: There's one bump in physical space, so a series of bumps in frequency space

I think he's describing what the process looks like in $k$ space. There, sound propagation is just oscillation with frequency $\omega=c_\mathrm{s}k$, where $c_\mathrm{s}$ is the sound speed. These plane-wave modes oscillate until recombination, when they freeze at whatever oscillation phase they were at.
